# «Ondulação» é um sinônimo para «flutuação»?

Tags: significado, sinônimos

Do livro "O Gaúcho" de José de Alencar.

> Como são melancólicas e solenes, ao pino do sol, as vastas campinas
>   que cingem as margens do Uruguai e seus afluentes! A savana se
>   desfralda a perder de vista, ondulando pelas sangas e coxilhas que
>   figuram as **flutuações** das vagas nesse verde oceano. Mais profunda
>   parece aqui a solidão, e mais pavorosa, do que na imensidade dos
>   mares.

Podemos dizer que, de acordo com o contexto acima, '**flutuações**' é o mesmo que '**ondulações**'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

José de Alencar, escritor brasileiro do século XIX, usa em "O Gaúcho" um vocabulário regional, restrito ao Estado do Rio Grande do Sul.

> > TEXTO - 
> >     A savana se desfralda a perder de vista, ondulando pelas *sangas* e *coxilhas* que figuram as flutuações das vagas nesse verde oceano.  Mais profunda parece aqui a solidão, e mais pavorosa, do que na imensidade dos mares.
>
> - [**"coxilha"**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxilha_(relevo)) -  é uma colina localizada em regiões de campos, podendo ter pequena ou grande elevação, em geral coberta de pastagem.
> - [**"sanga"**](https://www.dicio.com.br/sanga/) -  córrego que seca com facilidade. "ribeira" em pt-PT.

Bem, não me considero letrado o suficiente para fazer análise literária, mas entendo da seguinte forma: (em **negrito** a interpretação de **"figuram as flutuações."**)

A savana, extensa e a perder de vista, apresenta ondulações formadas por colinas e córregos secos. Essas ondulações **lembram o contorno e a imagem do subir e descer de ondas**, nesse oceano formado pela extensa savana. A solidão percebida pelo autor nesse panorama, é descrita como "mais perturbadora do que aquela percebida nos verdes mares do nosso planeta".

O autor utiliza uma figura de linguagem (a metáfora) ao referir-se ao sobe e desce das colinas como "vagas" e à imensa savana verde como "oceano".

Comment: Note que **Vagas** é um termo (arcaico?) sinônimo de **Ondas**. Com certeza utilizando um vocabulário mais "moderno" você pode sim substituir flutuações por ondulações

Comment: @jean   Sim, vagas é um sinônimo para ondas. Foi, ainda é, e está implícito na resposta acima.  Sim, podemos substituir flutuações por ondulações.  Mas eu preferi explicar o que, na paisagem descrita pelo autor,  corresponde às flutuações (são o sobre e desce do verde das colinas).

Comment: @jean Vaga/vagas não é arcaico.